# Working with Git, Svn and Eclipse Together

Tags: eclipse, git, svn

I am trying to find the right way to do this. My firm is using SVN as we are working on the projects to do checkin and checkouts. But I am thinking about using Git to backup all my work as I got home.. here is why

From Home I don't have access to my firms SVN Repo so I was thinking about setting up a Git Repo on the internet to checkin all my work into git before I leave work so I can access it from home.

I would like to hear if others are doing this and if you think this is a good practice.

How would I do this?  I been using SVN and Eclipse for sometime now but I hear GIT would be better for cloning my workstation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this for many people is 'git svn'. It allows you to create a local git repo as a clone of a tree in svn, work locally, and commit your work back to svn.

You can run git svn while at work, copy the resulting repo to a disk you carry home, and then commit back to svn when you get back to work. Always assuming, of course, that your employer's policies permit this. If you can't get to svn from home, perhaps they don't like anything about this idea.

Comment: Ooh, I have to look into this!

Comment: what do you mean but this.. I don't want a local get repo.. I am going to have a remote one so I can get my work from home.  but can you please tell me why someone would want to work with git locally and svn for team?

Comment: Ideally the entire team would be using git.

Comment: no my team is using SVN and I would like to use git just to clone my workstation